# CDF of random variables

Tags: probability

due to my lack of knowledge in probability theory, I have first to apologize if the following question is not formulated in a proper language. I was wondering if there is any formal expression of the mass cumulative distribution function of a random variable $X$ having a step (or simple) function  f(x)$ as mass density function.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

For every random variable $X$ with PDF $f_X$, whether $f_X$ is continuous or not, the CDF $F_X$ of $X$ is defined, for every $x$, by $$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf_X(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$